# Cleanest way to check if table exists - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, prepared-statement

Working with C# and MySQL here (Visual Studio 12 and MySQL workbench 6.1).

This is what I have so far.

```
string strCheck = "SHOW TABLES LIKE \'emp\'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strCheck, con);
cmd.Prepare();

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("exists");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("does not");
}
```

I have seen many questions here (mostly related to PHP) but they don't seem to be working for me. Also, I don't want a solution where we check if the table has any rows, because the table can be empty, and what I want to know is *whether it exists.*

Thanks.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` will return number of rows affected and I think you not affecting any rows in your SQL statement. Try to use `Reader`.

Comment: @Reniuz so MySqlCommand.Reader() ?

Comment: `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); if(reader.HasRows) Console.WriteLine("Exists")` or `if(reader.Read()) ...`

Comment: @Reniuz doesn't work. Gives a false positive.

Comment: @Reniuz Update: Changed the query and works with your method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT
        `TABLE_NAME`
    FROM
        `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
    WHERE
        (`TABLE_NAME` = 'emp')
        AND
        (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydb')
) as `is-exists`;
```

Comment: Keep in mind: You need MySQL 5.0 to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: @KenanZahirovic OP is using `Visual Studio 12 and MySQL workbench 6.1`. I do really have a doubt, that OP has old database engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mind implementing this in the above C# code segment?

Comment: @SuperJohn Well, I do not actually strong in `C#`.  I suggest you to follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787097/mysql-select-where-and-c-sharp).

Comment: I solved the problem. My previous query works but I had to use `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); if(reader.HasRows) Console.WriteLine("Exists")`. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @john Then the accepted answer is not the answer, your comment is the answer